# How to use EXPECT_EQ and other Google Mock statement in an inline callback function?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

Say that I have this test case:

```
TEST_F(TestCase1, HappyCase){
    foo->doSomething(arg1, new inlineCallback([=](bool success){
        EXPECT_EQ(success, true);
    }));
}
```

But:

```
EXPECT_EQ(success, true)
```

will only be called when you actually call **inlineCallback** passing a boolean in the implementation of **doSomething** function of the foo class.

But it could be that the implementation is very complex and there is chance that inlineCallback will never be called, then EXPECT_EQ(success, true) will not be called and this test case is pretty much useless.

How can I always make sure that EXPECT_EQ(success, true) will always be evaluated?

Comment: `new inlineCallback` may I just say ick.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do it is to also capture a boolean by reference and to set that to true in the callback:

```
TEST_F(TestCase1, HappyCase) {
    bool callback_called = false;

    foo->doSomething(arg1, new inlineCallback([&callback_called, =](bool success) {
        callback_called = true;
        EXPECT_TRUE(success);
    }

    EXPECT_TRUE(callback_called);
}
```

If your callbacks all have a common (abstract) base class they inherit from (which the existence of the `inlineCallback` class strongly suggests) then you can also use Googlemock and its argument matchers instead:

```
// assuming this is the callback interface
class Callback {
public:
     Callback() = default;
     Callback(Callback const&) = delete;
     Callback(Callback&&) = delete;
     Callback& operator=(Callback const&) = delete;
     Callback& operator=(Callback&&) = delete;
     virtual ~Callback() = default;

     virtual void operator()(bool) = 0;
};

class MockCallback : public Callback {
public:
    // since Googlemock can't mock operators directly we add one level 
    // of indirection
    MOCK_METHOD1(calledWith, void(bool));

    void operator()(bool const arg) override { 
      calledWith(arg);
    }
};

TEST_F(TestCase1, HappyCase) {
    auto callback = std::make_unique<::testing::StrictMock<MockCallback>>();

    EXPECT_CALL(*callback, calledWith(true));

    foo->doSomething(arg1, callback.release());
}
```